# How to add properties in PropertyGrid from the database?

Tags: c#, propertygrid

I have around 30 elements/objects for which i need PropertyGrid to show their properties in it,but the problem is that every object has different properties so i created a database for it.
I don't know how to add properties in PropertyGrid from the Database.

Comment: It is completely unclear why you think you need a database.  PropertyGrid certainly doesn't, it uses reflection.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume that you are using Windows Forms, since you are asking about `PropertyGrid`. If you have objects (meaning classes) that have the properties you want to display in your `PropertyGrid`, you need only to set [PropertyGrid.SelectedObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.propertygrid.selectedobject.aspx) with the object you want to display. By default, `PropertyGrid` will use reflection to find all the public properties of your object, and will display them.

You can use various attributes to control how `PropertyGrid` displays properties. For example, you can apply the [Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) attribute to a class property to add help text that the property grid will display. You can use the [Browsable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute.aspx) attribute to control whether `PropertyGrid` will display a given property. There are other attributes in the [System.ComponentModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z82ykwhb.aspx) namespace that you can use.